# Modifying the web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm uploading a project to a GoDaddy server and running into a problem when I try to modify the web.config file before I upload. Specifically, I want to add the following so I don't have to edit my web.config on the server every time I publish:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>
<system.web>
```

Comment: when you publish to the server, what build configuration are you using? If you publish with "debug" configuration, then it should indeed transform your web.config according to the items in web.debug.config. But if you publish using "Release" or some other build profile that you added, then you'd need to create a transform file for that configuration instead.

Comment: I am using the debug configuration.

Comment: In theory, everything you need to know about config transformations ought to be [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) . It's possible you need to add an `xdt:Transform` attribute to the system.web section in the debug.config, or to the two items you want to insert.

Comment: Updated the original, the xdt:Transform fixed that problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's great. Instead of editing your question though, if you found a solution please add it as an Answer below, then people can see clearly there is a fix for the issue, and can vote on it. You are allowed to answer your own question. And the solution is not part of the question!

Comment: Noted, and done.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a xdt:Transform fixed this problem.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">    
  </customErrors>
  <trust level="Full" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
  </trust>
</system.web>
```